# multiple USB 2.0 devices faster on USB 3.0?

Tags: usb-3, usb-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using USB 3.0 to speed up transfer between USB 2.0 devices?](https://superuser.com/questions/278670/using-usb-3-0-to-speed-up-transfer-between-usb-2-0-devices)

I know USB 2.0 maxes out at 480Mbps, and USB 3.0 maxes out at 4800Mbps.  Can multiple USB 2.0 devices tap into that USB 3.0 bandwidth?  For example, if I have a USB 2.0 device that can use 480Mbps and I hook up 10 of them to a USB 3.0 controller, will each USB 2.0 device max out at 480Mbps or 48Mbps.

Comment: USB 2.0 devices are limited to USB 2.0 Speeds when connected to a USB 3.0 port that accepts both USB 2.0/3.0 devices.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not going to work in that way. when you plug a usb2.0 device to usb3.0 port of your computer, the computer uses usb2.0 specifications (drivers) i.e 480mbps.

Answer (score 0):

They would still max out at USB 2.0 because the computer detects the device is USB 2.0 and treats it as such.